# Using NumLock key as End key

Tags: keyboard

I have a Asus n551 laptop.  It's mostly usable despite an inconvenient touchpad, Optimus graphics card that complicate things and a screen that shows major (depending on your sensitivity) color banding.

Anyway, its keyboard lacks a <kbd>End</kbd> key, which is a problem for me as I use it a lot.

It has a <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key, though, which I don't use, and which is at the same position where, on my previous laptop, was the <kbd>End</kbd> key (on that previous laptop there was no <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key...).

Can the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key be comfortably used as an <kbd>End</kbd> key?

Comment: One problem I would see is disabling the laptop's built in usage of the NumLock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this was tricky to get right.

### Sort-of solution

Adding this to a `~/.Xmodmap` file somehow does the trick:

```
keycode 77 = End NoSymbol End
```

For immediate effect,

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

If works very well, for simple keypresses as with shift and control keys.

### Now what about <kbd>NumLock</kbd>?

But now another problem is that the `NumLock` toggle is disabled, and the keypad perform arrow-like actions instead of typing numbers.

#### Here comes `numlockx` and fail:

```
$ numlockx status
Numlock is off
$ numlockx on
$ numlockx status
Numlock is off
```

Hum, strange.

#### <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> (key) as `Num_Lock` (keysym). Works, but inconvenient.

I tried

```
keycode 77 = End Num_Lock End
```

but though it allows to do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> to toggle keypad behavior, it hinders <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, a combination that I often use while typing (select to end-of-line).

#### Keypad-divide as `Num_Lock`. Fail.

I tried the key next to it:

```
keycode 77 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 106 = Num_Lock KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
```

or even

```
keycode 77 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 106 = Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock
```

but pressing that key did not have any effect.

Actually, `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` seems to reset `NumLock` toggle to false.

Same for the <kbd>²</kbd> `twosuperior` key which I don't use for typing:

```
keycode 49 = Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock Num_Lock
```

### Tricky solution

It looks like if the keycode 77 is not bound to `Num_Lock` at all, then `NumLock` toggle is always kept at false.

Let's assign it (in `~/.Xmodmap`) some combination so obscure that I can't figure out:

```
keycode 77 = End NoSymbol End Num_Lock
```

Then

```
$ numlockx on
$ numlockx status
Numlock is on
```

### Conclusion: success

- I can use the physical <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key as <kbd>End</kbd> key with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>.
- `numlockx on` works, for the rare case I will need it.

### Additional information

- French keyboard layout on Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Just noticed a drawback: even with all this stuff each press on the "num lock" key sets the flag to off.  A workaround is to have numlockx enable it at all times: `nohup bash -c "while sleep 1 ; do numlockx on ; done" &`

Something simpler might be possible.