# Is there a way to reconfigure function keys on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: keyboard, 19.04, function-keys

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on HP ProBook 450 G6 and noticed my function keys for increasing/decreasing brightness both act as toggling microphone, the rest works fine (and everything works fine on Win 10). I have two questions:

- Is there a way to reconfigure actions for those two keys?
- Is this a bug that I should report to Canonical?

Comment: I found something online, the keys are Fn+F3 and Fn+F4 https://i2.wp.com/laptopmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/DSC08936.jpg

Comment: `button/f20 F20 00000080 00000000 K` for both buttons

Comment: you probably meant the actual toggle mic Fn+F8, right? it's the same output

Comment: yes, fn+f8 works as expected, fn+f2 or f9 trigger no event, `VOLDN` `VOLUP` for volume buttons

Comment: `keycode 198 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute` that was the only line in output

Answer (score 0):

1. open terminal and run `xmodmap -pke | grep MonBrightness`

example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep MonBrightness
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
pratap@i7:~$
```

2. Copy the lines after = for both BrighnessDown and up
3. Once the keycodes for fn+f3 and fn+f4 are known
4. `xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown"`
5. `xmodmap -e "keycode yyy = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp"`

once you logout above commands 4 and 5 will not persist..

to make them persist follow this thread https://askubuntu.com/a/1131511/739431

Comment: so after I tried to find the keycodes for the keys, it turns out that all 3 keys are mapped to the same keycode - which is whole another problem... so changing action works, but will affect 3 keys again

Comment: that is what it is supposed to be, but `showkey` shows it all maps to the same keycode... seems like a bug tied up to the notebook model, not sure if there is a way to fix that

Comment: yes, in windows it's working... that goes on Canonical side, I will probably fill bug report

Comment: can you please specify in the answer how to map action with ctrl/alt key? I suppose that's what the `NoSymbol` is for... I'll then accept the answer, thanks for the help

Comment: yes, I can do that, I was more wondering about how to do it through `xmodmap`

Comment: xmodmap requires keycode for fn+f3 or fn+f4 etc.. in your case the keycode is same? rite.. so its not possible to proceed with xmodmap.. you can assign custom keyboard shortcuts with ctrl+f3 with the command `xdotool sleep 0.5 key XF86MonBrightnessDown` you need to install xdotool package.. `sudo apt install xdotool`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1103370/739431 can you check this thread.. it seems some patch is required from the vendor..